What Is the Best Way to Analyse Prepositional Phrases in Post-Head Position Containing a Pre-head Adverb?
In the following sentence, what is the best approach to analyse the phrase 'currently with Jack'?

[2] The girl currently with Jack doesn't know what's in store for her.

Without the adverb 'currently,' it would, in my opinion, be an overt prepositional phrase. However, when combined with the temporal adjunct 'currently,' I think the analysis could take two directions.
I believe we could class the example phrase as a prepositional phrase, even with 'currently,' as adverbs can function as pre-head adjuncts in a prepositional phrase (as discussed by the Cambridge Dictionary here). But it could also be viewed as a reduced relative clause, expanding to the clause below:

[2] The girl who is currently with Jack doesn't know what's in store for her.

The reason I say this is that the adverb 'currently' in the relative clause would be analysed (according to the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language), I think, as a clausal adjunct, not a pre-head adjunct of the prepositional phrase. There are clear differences, so I think there are two possible ways to analyse it.

Have you considered the more specific type of reduction known as [tag:whiz-deletion]?

@tchrist, I've always mentally placed whiz-deletion in the same category as reduced relative clauses, but I'll have a further read around that.

When modifying an adjective in a similar situation, the reduced relative explanation would be unlikely. Compare:

[The currently available data] points to a further increase in
2022.
vs
[The data currently available] points to a further increase in
2022.

In the first case, the only available analysis would be that currently modifies available as part of the pre-head modifier. Surely no one would argue for a reduced clause here. So why argue for one when the dependent has been moved to the post-head position?
Then, when with has the meaning of have, the reduced relative explanation would also not be available.

The prison, currently with a population of 1,459, serves as an intake center where new arrivals can spend up to six months before being transferred to a permanent facility to complete their sentence. (Marion Star)

Further, similar modifiers could appear as supplements in clause structure.

Currently with Rennes, it is widely expected that Camavinga will get a move to a bigger club this summer. (TBR Football)

Again, we'd not be able to argue that there is a reduced relative clause involved here, unless it was reduced and then preposed.
Some of these might be argued as verbless clauses if they are open to expansion with further adjuncts.

The girl, currently with Jack because he's rich, doesn't know what's in
store for her.

In any case, the reduced relative explanation does not seem to be applicable to these sorts of items systematically, only when in post-head position in a noun phrase, and only when the preposition and meaning in question would work in a standard relative clause.
In general, be only shows up when it's structurally required, like in a main clause where there's only a subject and a subject oriented complement, or for clarity. To say it has been reduced or deleted might make sense when comparing these to main clauses with similar meanings, but imagining ghost components when they're not needed, and not even allowed in some cases, seems a little excessive.
It's much clearer to say that NPs can take PPs as post-head modifiers, and those can in turn be modified by AdvPs.

Excellent answer! I like that you referenced verbless clauses, as it's those that have led me to question whether certain constituents (such as 'because he's rich' and 'currently') are modifiers of what they're positioned alongside. I think your analysis—that we shouldn't insert 'ghost components' when they are easily explained without them—is the best approach.
